# Is there a way to replace many if statements with a faster way

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have a program to automate a form filling. But the bot is very slow due to the fact that it has to check each statements. Is there a way to make it faster. Thanks.

```
import pyautogui, time
x=1098
y=433
pyautogui.click(x, y)
if pyautogui.locateOnScreen("q1.png") is not None:
    pyautogui.click("r1.png", button="left")
    pyautogui.click("check.png", button="left")
    pyautogui.click("continue.png", button="left")
if pyautogui.locateOnScreen("q2.png") is not None:
    pyautogui.click("r2.png", button="left")
    pyautogui.click("check.png", button="left")
    pyautogui.click("continue.png", button="left")
if pyautogui.locateOnScreen("q3.png") is not None:
    pyautogui.click("r3.png", button="left")
    pyautogui.click("check.png", button="left")
    pyautogui.click("continue.png", button="left")
if pyautogui.locateOnScreen("q4.png") is not None:
    pyautogui.click("r4.png", button="left")
    pyautogui.click("check.png", button="left")
    pyautogui.click("continue.png", button="left")
```

I put only 4 if statements, but I have more than a hundred in my script.

Comment: the `if` is not the part that needs to be faster. It's quite likely the `locateOnScreen`. Repetitive lookups is not a good algorithm

Comment: You can make a list of tuples from the names, e.g. `buttonlist = [("q1.png", "r1.png"), ("q2.png", "r2.png"), ...]`, and then iterate the list. Whether that's going to be faster is debatable, but it's certainly a lot less typing.

Comment: To get real speed improvement, you need to check the pyautogui documentation and see if there's a method that returns the list of images on the screen. Then you can turn things around. Iterate the list of screen images, and add a button for each image. I'm assuming that there are far fewer images on the screen than you have in the list of all possible images.

Comment: I know nothing about pyautogui. However, I can tell you that the right way to do this is with a control structure of some kind (perhaps a dictionary) and you apply the "rules" to that. Then you just iterate over the dictionary and apply those rules in a concise piece of code. Of course, if the png filenames fit a well-known pattern (qN, rN etc) then you could just use a numbered loop

Comment: @Vlad The dictionary method would solve this issue if the bottleneck were the if statements, and if it were if elif elif elif.  However, in this case, the bottleneck is the locateOnScreen function, so switching to dictionary lookups won't help.

Comment: Is this a form in a non-browser program running on the user's computer, or is it a form in a browser?  If it is in a browser and you are writing a crawler, then the correct answer is probably to use Selenium instead of pyautogui.  If this is a non-browser-based form though, I have no idea.

Comment: @kloddant Agreed - But a control structure makes the code more manageable. As I said, I know nothing about pyautogui so if locateOnScreen is an issue then that's another matter altogether